# How can I loop through and Save values into an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following loop goes through the sales column and lists all 4 existing product values, like `19.99 19.99 3.99 3.99` to the corresponding user id.

```
    <% @sales.each_with_index do |sale, index| %>
     <% if current_user.id == sale.user_id %>
      <% price = Warehouse.where(:product => sale.product).pluck(:mrr) %>
      <%= value = price.split(',').join('.').to_f %>
    <% else %>
    <% end %>
```

Now I want to save the results/values into a new global variable and add up each out of "value". So the result of `19.99 19.99 3.99 3.99` should be `47.96`.

I'm completely lost. Any Ideas?

Comment: Create a variable, initialize it to zero before the loop, and add `value` to it in the loop?

Comment: @DaveNewton that does not help, as it does not add up each value from the variable.

Comment: ... How do you figure? You're iterating over values and adding them up. What's the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<% total = 0 %>
<% @sales.each_with_index do |sale, index| %>
  <% if current_user.id == sale.user_id %>
    <% price = Warehouse.where(:product => sale.product).pluck(:mrr) %>
    <%= value = price.split(',').join('.').to_f %>
    <% total += value %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= "Total is #{total}" %>
```

It is highly questionable to have code like this in the view though. You could get prices and calculate totals in your controller instead.

Also note that you are missing an `end`. I changed the unneeded `else` to an `end`.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can create a instant `variable prefixed by @` so it can be used throughout your view

For example in your controller

```
@total_value = 0
```

And in your view

```
<%@sales.each_with_index do |sale, index| %>
     <% if current_user.id == sale.user_id %>
      <% price = Warehouse.where(:product => sale.product).pluck(:mrr) %>
      <%= value = price.split(',').join('.').to_f %>
      <% @total_value += value %>
    <% else %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add that kind of logic in your view. Create a view object class (that the controller instantiates) too handle all of this. You also probably can do something like:

```
user.sales.each do |sale|
  total += find_price(sale)
  # do more stuff
end
```

If you are asking 'if current_user.id == sale.user_id' then you most likely doing it wrong.

In that view object you could have a hash that has all the prices you want to show and iterate over that in your view.